# Is $P_\omega$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G_\omega$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

We have the following theorem

> Let $G$ be a group, acting on a set $\Omega$ and let $p^m\Bigm||\omega^G|$ wherein $p$ is prime and $\omega \in \Omega$. If $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ then, $p^m\Bigm||\omega^P|$.

In this theorem $\omega^G=\{\omega^g|g\in G\}$ is any orbit of $(G|\Omega)$. The proof is easy and it is based of using **Orbit-Stabilizer Equation** for $G$ and $P$. As theorem takes, I assume that the group $G$ acts on a set $\Omega$. we can prove that for any subgroup $H$ of $G$,  $H_\omega$ is a subgroup of $G_\omega$ where $G_\omega$ is the stablizer of $\omega$. I am asking kindly: Can we say that $P_\omega$ is a $p-$ Sylow subgroup of $G_\omega$ when $P$ is a $p-$ Sylow subgroup of $G$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Some conjugate of P works like this, but maybe not P itself. Let G be S3 and P be S2 and w be 1. Then Pw is 1 and is not a Sylow of Gw which is its own Sylow of order 2.

Comment: I think the abstract groups G where this always works are exactly the nilpotent groups.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Is this useful if I know that $(P|\Omega)$ transitively?

Comment: @JackSchmidt: It seems to me if we assume $(P|\Omega)$ be transitive so, $(G|\Omega)$ will be and then the index of $P_\omega$ in $G_\omega$ is free of $p$. Am I right?

Comment: Yup. If P is transitive your argument is good.